# Find the trace of the 9th power of A.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the trace of the 9th power of A. I have searched for solutions on the internet but all of it requires knowledge on eigenvectors and diagonalisation. However, in my course we only learned up till elementary row operations using matrices.

A=\begin{pmatrix}a&0&b\\ \:\:b&a&0\\ \:\:0&b&a\end{pmatrix}

Comment: $A = aI + b\pmatrix{0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0}.$  Lets call that matrix $\omega.$   Apply the binomial theorem.   Note that $\omega^3 = I$

Comment: Wow i see it now! Thank you will try it when I get home. The matrix was also given as a hint from a previous part so this makes sense all the more.

Comment: Still, the result is not so easy. In fact, the trace is $$3(a^6 + 83a^3b^3 + b^6)(a^2 - ab + b^2)(a + b)$$ It makes sense to use a CAS.

Comment: A ridiculous exericse. Either it is too complicated or pointless (depending on whether electronic help is allowed)